# Is that possible to create IE toolbar using WPF?

Tags: .net, wpf, ieaddon

I just start learning WPF, is that possible I can create an IE toolbar by using WPF, if so, is there any document about how to do that?

Thanks a lot.

Comment: given that you have, by your own admission, just starting learning WPF, do you think you are setting the bar a bit high?

Comment: @Mitch: Doesn't this relate to someone's question of "what .net gives me that win32 doesn't?" I mean, there are things (many), for which .net is not a good choice (yet).

Comment: @Mitch: it is just a question came up to my mind while I start reading the WPF documents. I am obviously not able to do it right now, but I really like to hear some advice from some experts. I feel it will help me to learn WPF.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could technically implement a toolbar with WPF but there is a potential issue with this or other approaches that uses managed code. There can only be one version of the .NET CLR loaded into the IE process so if you need .NET 3.5 and .NET 1.0 has been loaded you could be in trouble.

You can implement the COM interfaces required to create an IE toolbar with WPF, and you might want to look at some WinForms [examples](http://www.google.com/search?ie=UTF-8&oe=UTF-8&sourceid=navclient&gfns=1&q=c%23+ie+extension) for the basics.

Products like [Add-in Express](http://www.add-in-express.com/docs/internet-explorer-extensions.php) claim to make programming IE extensions with managed code easier and safer.

Comment: Actually, .NET 3.5 and 2.0 both use the 2.0 CLR, so that should be ok. If there's already a 1.x add-in loaded then that would prove a problem.

Comment: Brian, thanks a lot for the help, I never know that "There can only be one version of the .NET CLR loaded into the IE process". wow, so if some other addons already load a version of .net then addons programmed by managed code with different .net CLR will not be able to work. That is a very weird design for IE.

Seems using C/C++ to create IE toolbar is still the best choice. It is very interesting the Add-in-express you provided. 

Thanks a lot for your help.